# A simple dictionary list in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need some help please. I'm noob in jQuery and I try to create a dictionary list.

But my problematic is that each definition must be displayed under his own row of 3 words (desktop), 2 words (in tablet) and under his own word (accordion system) in mobile. One definition must be displayed at a time. I would like to toggle definition when I click on a word.

Wordpress will be use to add words so the list must be dynamic.

Here my incomplete test : https://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/qbh79xoy/31/

```
$('.tabs .tab-link').each(function (index, item) {
   $(item).attr('data-link', index);
});

$('.tab-content .tab-content').each(function (index, item) {
   $(item).attr('data-content', index);
});

$('.tabs .tab-link').click(function () {
    $('.tabs .tab-link').not(this).removeClass('current');    
    $(this).toggleClass('current');
});
```

I don't know what I must write to display each definition under a row of 3 words. Can I have some help please ? Thank you in advance.

**DESKTOP VERSION**

[image]

**MOBILE VERSION**

[image]

Comment: looking at your html structure, i don't think it suits your use case.

Comment: @Ji_in_coding, what structure can I use instead ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use media queries, media queries change CSS rules depending on criteria such as screen width.

For example the following **width** rule won't apply for screens wider than **480px**:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

And the following **width** rule won't apply for screens wider than **769px**:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
  body {
    width: 33%;
  }
}
```

You can have as much media queries as you need.

For more info about media queries see [this w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: In fact my problem is not about the way to do the responsive. But to display definition under each row of 3 words.